# Adding a second html page in a Create React App project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've been developing an embeddable widget using CreateReactApp. It works great when initialised from the index.html

Now I want to test what happens when the user changes page in the html. Ill need to save the app's state in storage etc.

When I add a second html page to the public folder (two.html) and navigate to it - I get the error:

```
URI Error: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico'
```

..and the app js does not run.

How can update my app so I can use a second html page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe caused due to babel not able to transpile the % .
Please try updating this in index.html :

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/public/favicon.ico" />
```